# Shell does not open when trying to open shell with Assembly code

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, shellcode

I am trying to open a shell code using the following assembly code where I have tried to use JUMP CALL POP method.

```
.section .text
.globl main
main:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    pushl %ebx
    subl $0xc, %esp         
    jmp end
hop:
    popl %ebx
    movl %ebx, -0xc(%ebp)   
    movl $0, -0x4(%ebp)

    movl $59, %eax                            
    leal -0xc(%ebp), %ecx                 
    movl $0, %edx                       
    int  $0x80              
    leave
    ret
end:
    call hop 
    .asciz       "/bin/sh\0"
```

I am running the code in x86_64 with the following commands

```
gcc -m32 file.s
GCC -m32 -o file file.s
./file
```

In this case, nothing occurs, and no shell open up.

What might be the possible issue in my code? Debugging with gdb indicates that %ebx and %eax are correctly loaded. But still the shell does not open up.

Comment: Run your code under a debugger to see which instruction it faults on.  You don't want actual core files, that's a waste of time when you want to debug on the same machine you're running on.  `gdb ./file` / `layout reg` / `run`.  Your code looks over-complicated; storing two `0` dwords to the stack, one relative to EBP and one relative to ESP is weird.  Also note that Linux `execve` allows you to just pass a NULL pointer as the `argv` and `env` inputs, treating that as equivalent to an empty array (pointer to a NULL in memory)

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the code to a simpler version. GDB shows that %eax and %ebx are loaded correctly. By pointing NULL, do you mean I don't have to do anything for env and argv?

Comment: I mean you can `xor %ecx,%ecx` and same for EDX.  You can't leave garbage in them, that would potentially lead to the system call returning with `-EFAULT` if they're non-zero but not pointing to valid memory.  Probably that's what's happening now; use `strace ./file` to decode your system call args and return value.  (Since you're building a program with a `main`, not `_start`, there will be a bunch of systems calls from dynamic linking and CRT / libc startup code before execution gets to main for your `execve`, and then a couple after as your return from main.)

Comment: Actually, since this is an execve syscall, you can't leave NULL in %ecx or %edx either -- they need to be valid pointers to argv and envp arrays or the syscall will fail with EFAULT